# How to access embedding layer's variables in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, embedding, tensorflow2.x

Suppose I have the embedding layer `e` like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
e = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(5,3)
```

How can I print its numpy values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @vald for his answer. I think `e.embeddings` is more pythonic and maybe efficient.

```
import tensorflow as tf
e = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(5,3)

e.build(()) # You should build it before using.

print(e.embeddings)
```

---

```
>>>
<tf.Variable 'embeddings:0' shape=(5, 3) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.02099125,  0.01865673,  0.03652272],
       [ 0.02714007, -0.00316695, -0.00252246],
       [-0.02411103,  0.02043924, -0.01297874],
       [ 0.00766286, -0.03511617,  0.03460207],
       [ 0.00256425, -0.03659264, -0.01796588]], dtype=float32)>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to *build* embedding layer before you can access embedding matrix:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(5, 3)
emb.build(())
emb.trainable_variables[0].numpy()
# array([[-0.00595363,  0.03049802,  0.01821234],
#        [ 0.01515153, -0.01006874,  0.02568189],
#        [-0.01845006,  0.02135053, -0.03916124],
#        [-0.00822829,  0.00922295,  0.00091892],
#        [-0.00727308, -0.03537174, -0.01419405]], dtype=float32)
```